# Quick question on poles

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, contour-integration

Consider this function for $0 < a < b$:

$$f_{(z)} = \frac{z^4}{z^2(z-\frac{a}{b})(z-\frac{b}{a})}$$

This function has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$, a pole of order 1 at $z=\frac{a}{b}$, but what about the pole at $z=\frac{b}{a}$? Why isn't it mentioned in the book?

Here's the original question:

Evaluate

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos 2\theta}{a^2 + b^2 -2ab \cos \theta} d\theta$$

Then by using subsitution of $z = e^{i\theta}$ we arrive at the form above.

Is the reason they are ignoring the $z=\frac{b}{a}$ term because it is greater than 1, so it lies outside the circle, where residue theorem doesn't work?

Comment: Depends what the book says. Are there conditions on $a$ and $b$? For example, if $b > a$, then $b/a>1$, which perhaps is not of interest for some reason?

Comment: The usual way to detect a pole is if you plug in a point, your function goes kaboom, which this clearly does if you plug in $b/a$.Your integral is probably around the unit circle, which $b/a$ is not inside. That is probably why they ignored it.

Comment: The original question asks to $\int \frac{z^4}{z^2(z-\frac{a}{b})(z-\frac{b}{a})} dz $. The book evaluates this by using residue theorem.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, because by residue theorem, the integral of a function in a circle about path C, is the equal to $2\pi i \sum_j R_j$. So if a singularity doesn't lie inside the circle, we don't need to consider it.

Comment: Exactly Right! :)

Comment: Great question! Fond memories reading this in Ahlfors.

Comment: Hmm, this function does not have a pole at $z=0$--the singularity there is removable, right? Note the presence of $z^4$ in the numerator. Once the singularity is removed, the function actually has a zero at $z=0$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can interchange $a$ and $b$ in the integral and the integrand remains unchanged. So without loss of generality, we can choose $b>a$. Then the substitution $z=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ parameterises the unit circle, which will contain the poles at $z=0$ and $z=a/b$, but not the pole at $z=b/a$.